# Item position in an array

Tags: php

If I have id number and an array in the following format, how do I find out what count (position number) 'Red' among all other items where cat == 4? The answer I am looking for #3 of 4.
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [cat] => 1
                [que] => Description here.
            )

```
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [cat] => 1
            [que] => Description here.
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [cat] => 1
            [que] => Description here.
        )
 ....

    [31] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 32
            [cat] => 4
            [que] => Description here.
        )

    [32] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 33
            [cat] => 4
            [que] => Description here.
        )
    [33] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 34
            [cat] => 4
            [que] => Red.
        )

    [34] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 35
            [cat] => 4
            [que] => Description here.
        )
)
```

Do I need to split array and then loop? Lost...

--------- EDIT ----------

OK, I did a bad job explaining...

What I meant was: there are many objects withing this array. They are broken into groups, categories. [cat] is the value for each group. There are multiple items in each group. What I was hoping to get was a number of items in each group and the position of particular item withing that group, for example:  4 out of 12.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking

Comment: Look at [cat]. It's the id of a group. I am looking for an item position number withing that group.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. How come the answer is #3 of 4, if there are apparently 35 elements in the array? Where does the 3 come from, if the first element which has `cat == 4` is 31? What is `'Red'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$position = 0;
$counts = array();

foreach ($yourarray as $obj) {
    if (!isset($counts[$obj->cat])) $counts[$obj->cat] = 0;
    $counts[$obj->cat]++;
    if ($obj->cat == 4 && $obj->que == "Red") {
        $position = $counts[$obj->cat];
    }
}

if ($position >= 0) {
    echo "Object is $position out of $counts[4] objects in category 4\n";
}
foreach($counts as $key=>$val){
    echo "Category $key has $val objects.\n";
}
```

(Revised to count all categories)

Comment: I like this approach but when i try the code it breaks my AJAX response, at the following like: if ($subarray["cat"] == 4) {

Comment: @freejosh had it right with the object notation, for some reason I was thinking you had an array of arrays.  So, I think now you're saying you want to get a count of all the categories as well.  I've revised my answer to reflect that.  If that's not what you meant then I think freejosh has the correct answer.

Comment: No, I don't need to count categories. I need a count of items withing each category and the position of an item withing its category. Sorry I can't seem to get it right across very successfully...

Comment: That's what freejosh's answer does, and mine does the same plus returns the count for the other categories too.  I tested to be sure, creating an array like your example scenario, and when I ran it the result was "Object is position 3 out of 4 objects in category 4."

Answer (score 1):

My edit to Ian Shannon's answer was rejected, so here's what I was proposing, which builds on his by using object notation instead of array notation and keeps track of the total.

I think the simplest way would be to loop through the array with a foreach, and if cat == 4, increment a counter until you reach the one you want. Something like this:

```
$pos = 0;
$total = 0;
foreach ($yourarray as $subarray) {
    if ($subarray->cat == 4) {
        $total++;
        if ($subarray->que == "Red") {
            $pos = $total;
        }
    }
}
```

`$pos` will be the position of the element you're looking for, and `$total` will be the total in that category.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure this is exactly what I needed. What I meant is: there are many objects withing this array. They are broken into groups, categories. [cat] is the value for each group. There are multiple items in each group. What I was hoping to get was a number of items in each group and the position of particular item withing that group, for example:  4 out of 12.

Comment: @santa I still think my answer will do what you're describing. After running the loop you should be able to say "The item where que = Red is in position `$pos` out of `$total` objects with cat = 4".

Comment: @santa Are you saying you also want the loop to produce a list of how many items are in each category, regardless of the value of `cat`?

Comment: It's a bonus. Eventually I'll have a functionality that will allow including/excluding items from an array, so knowing how many items in a category dynamically would be great. For now I hard-code the total count, but I do need to know the position of specific item, based on it's overall ID in its group. Let's say, cat == 4 has 4 items, and I have id = 34. The output will be 3 of 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
$found = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($value->cat == '4'){
        $arrayPosition = $key;
        $found++;
    }
}

echo 'Found ' . $found . ' cat\'s, matching the criteria';
```

Didn't exactly understand what the matching criteria should be except for cat=4, and if "que" contains some more information you want to match, change the if statement.

```
if($value->cat == '4' && $value->que == 'Red'){
```